# JavaScript Convert to a dynamic Select Dropdown with array passed in function

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, drop-down-menu, input-field

I have this JavaScript function that works fine, but I want to alter it to accept an array passed in and use a loop in the function to access each element in the array.

Currently, the function is being passed the arguments separately as strings. `(input1, input2, input3)`. This is not practical because I'm using this function on many pages, and some pages may have more or less Inputs. It will be dynamic if I can pass an array and loop through it and get the same end functionality.

What it does is it hides the input fields if they are not selected in the dropdown. If I select `PO` from the dropdown, it displays that input field to enter the PO number into.

The function is initiated in the `onChange` event of the select.

Here is my original code.

**JavaSCript function:**

```
// javascript
function changetextbox(input1, input2, input3) {

    var sel = document.getElementById("sel");
    var in1 = document.getElementById(input1);
    var in2 = document.getElementById(input2);
    var in3 = document.getElementById(input3);
    var today = new Date();
    var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();

    if (sel.value === "All") {
        in1.style.display='none';
        in2.style.display='none';
        in3.style.display='none';
        in3.value = "";
    } else if (sel.value === input1) {
        in1.style.display='inline';
        in2.style.display='none';
        in3.style.display='none';
        in3.value = "";
    } else if (sel.value === input2) {
        in1.style.display='none';
        in2.style.display='inline';
        in3.style.display='none';
        in3.value = "";
    } else if (sel.value === input3) {
        in1.style.display='none';
        in2.style.display='none';
        in3.style.display='inline';
        in3.value = date;
    }
}
```

**Select Dropdown Form:**

```
<form method="post">
  <input type="text" id="PO" name="PO" value="" placeholder="Enter PO" style="display:none">
  <input type="text" id="OrderID" name="OrderID" value="" placeholder="Enter OrderID" style="display:none">
  <input type="date" id="CreatedTime" name="CreatedTime" value="" max="2018-11-30" style="display:none">
  <select id="sel" name="sel" onChange="changetextbox('PO, OrderID, CreatedTime');">
    <option value="All">All</option>
    <option value="PO">PO</option>
    <option value="OrderID">OrderID</option>
    <option value="CreatedTime">Date</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

This is my new code below which isn't working yet because I'm not sure what else exactly I need to do to it.

**JavaScript:**

```
function changetextbox(input) {

    var today = new Date();
    var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();

    var sel = document.getElementById("sel");
    var len = input.length;
    var inp;

    for (i=0; i<len; ++i) {
      if (i in input) {
        inp[i] = document.getElementById(input);

        if (sel.value === "All") {
            inp[i].style.display='none';
        } else {
            inp[i].style.display='inline';
        }

      }
    }
}
```

**Select Dropdown Form:**

```
<form method="post">
  <input type="text" id="PO" name="PO" value="" placeholder="Enter PO" style="display:none">
  <input type="text" id="OrderID" name="OrderID" value="" placeholder="Enter OrderID" style="display:none">
  <input type="date" id="CreatedTime" name="CreatedTime" value="" max="2018-11-30" style="display:none">
  <select id="sel" name="sel" onChange="changetextbox(dropdown);">
    <option value="All">All</option>
    <option value="PO">PO</option>
    <option value="OrderID">OrderID</option>
    <option value="CreatedTime">Date</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

JavaScript Array that is passed to the function

**JavaScript Variable:**

```
<script>
var dropdown = ["PO","OrderID","CreatedTime"];
</script>
```

Comment: can you post the error(s) you get and your best hypothesis on why it isn't working, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answer from Rikin, I edited it further to get the functionality I was looking for which is to hide all the inputs except for the one that corresponds to the selection in the dropdown.

The answer from Riken unhides all 3 inputs when a selection is made, and then hides all inputs if selection is All. In order to hide all inputs and only unhide the one that is selected in dropdown, I added `index-inputs` to his `map(function)`.

In plain terms this says,

`var index = sel.selectedIndex;` = the dropdown selection by key.

`index-inputs` = simply excludes the input from being hidden when it's selected from the dropdown.

```js
var dropdown = ["PO","OrderID","CreatedTime"];

function changetextbox(inputs) {
 
 function day_of_the_month(d) { 
   return (today.getDate() < 10 ? '0' : '') + today.getDate();
 }
 
 var today = new Date();
 var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+day_of_the_month(today);
 
 var sel = document.getElementById("sel");
 var index = sel.selectedIndex;
 var optVal = sel.options[index].value;
 var optTxt = sel.options[index].text;
 var inp = document.getElementById(optVal);
 
 index-inputs.map(function(input) {
   document.getElementById(input).style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById(input).value = '';
 });
 
 if(index !== 0) {
  if (inp.style.display === "none") {
   inp.style.display = "inline";
   
   if (optTxt === "Date" ) {
    inp.value = date;
   }
  }
 }

}
```

```html
<form method="post">
  <input type="text" id="PO" name="PO" value="" placeholder="Enter PO" style="display:none">
  <input type="text" id="OrderID" name="OrderID" value="" placeholder="Enter OrderID" style="display:none">
  <input type="date" id="CreatedTime" name="CreatedTime" value="" max="2018-12-02" style="display:none">
  <select id="sel" name="sel" onChange="changetextbox(dropdown);">
    <option value="All">All</option>
    <option value="PO">PO</option>
    <option value="OrderID">OrderID</option>
    <option value="CreatedTime">Date</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Removed distraction and concentrated on what you are probably looking for which is dynamic input passed to the function and set style based on selected input.

```js
var dropdown = ["PO", "OrderID", "CreatedTime"];

function myFunction(inputs) {
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
  var displayStyle = 'inline';
  if (x === 'All') displayStyle = 'none';
  inputs.map(function(input) {
    document.getElementById(input).style.display = displayStyle;
  });
}
```

```html
Select Dropdown Form:

<form method="post">
  <input type="text" id="PO" name="PO" value="" placeholder="Enter PO" style="display:none">
  <input type="text" id="OrderID" name="OrderID" value="" placeholder="Enter OrderID" style="display:none">
  <input type="date" id="CreatedTime" name="CreatedTime" value="" max="2018-11-30" style="display:none">

  <select id="mySelect" name="mySelect" onchange="myFunction(dropdown)">
    <option value="All">All</option>
    <option value="PO">PO</option>
    <option value="OrderID">OrderID</option>
    <option value="CreatedTime">Date</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Comment: Hi thank you. It works, but it unhides all 3 at the same time. I need it to unhide only the one that is selected in the dropdown and hide the other 2.